# do I need to show the post inline after a person posts?

Tags: social-interfaces

We have a site with a feed of activities people are doing and others can reply to those activities.  The current design has a place for replying in the feed but we don't want to show other replies there to keep from cluttering the design.  There will be a number of replies as a link to go to the post view (happening as a popout lightbox similar to pinterest's new feed/lightbox.)

We have a question about the user flow when they post - should they see the reply in the feed, similar to facebook/pinterest/etc or should I just show a confirmation message thanking them for their post with a link to the post?

On the one hand, I think it's normal to see what I replied right there - on the other hand, if I reloaded that feed page, I won't see my reply any more.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPUZfy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to help visualize whats happening?

Answer (score 3):

The scenario mentioned in mockup will work well in your case.

The comment is visible just after posting and will automatically hide after 5 seconds (can hide with an animation) and the link to number of replies can be highlighted.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjl28A.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: that might work - I'm a little concerned about making the post disappear completely - but I'll think about it more.